# Query Execution failed for a Report in CRM

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm, crm

We have a report that runs successfully on our testing crm environment but it throws this error on production (on-prem):

Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: Query execution failed for dataset 'myDataset'. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.

This error does not give much insight on what is going wrong.

Note: This report is fetching a lot of data and it takes around 5 to 10 minutes to render on dev - all the timeout settings on prod are exactly the same - also the service user has all the necessary permissions to execute the stored procedure used by that dataset.

Note2: When runnning the report on Report Builder or VS connecting to prod report server it runs without issues - only when deployed on CRM this error occurs.

What could possibly be wrong?

Comment: If it's not something obvious, check the data sources. They may point to the same server but with a different database. If the query doesn't specify the db in each table reference, it will get the `Query execution failed for dataset 'myDataset'` message.

Comment: data sources point to the correct database

Answer (score 0):

Most probable causes are deadlocks, timeouts and other resource issues. You may need to dive into the SQL Server logs. Dynamics CRM logging may also give you more info. Run the report outside office hours.

You may even need to redesign your query. E.g. it is not recommend to make extensive use of Filtered table joins. Also you may need to add table no lock hints.